# Multiple Instances on Windows

Tags: windows-7, tidesdk

This is what I found on Windows 7. A tide sdk app on windows creates new instance when double-clicked on the shortcut even if a previous instance already exists. You can observe the same thing on Tide SDK Developer(1.4.2) just run the application and if you click on the shortcut again it launches a new instance instead of just showing the already existing one. Does anyone know how to fix this? Or did anyone fixed this?

The OSX version doesn't display such problems though

Answer (score 0):

So i found a way to address this in windows. Create a process using Ti.Process and let it run the following command

```
tasklist | find "YourAppName"
```

If an instance already exists it returns that string, if not it returns an empty string. You can check this every time you start an app to avoid multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

Running `tasklist` in the background is platform-dependent, plus that solution only prevents a new instance from launching - it wouldn't focus an already running instance. There is another solution though which makes use of the `Ti.FileSystem.File.touch()` method: this method will attempt to create the specified file, and will return `true` if it succeeded, or `false` if the file already exists. Most importantly, it's atomic, meaning it shouldn't introduce a race condition to your app.

To focus the already running instance, you need to let it know it should (show and) focus itself. A working approach would be to run a HTTP server once the app knows it is the only instance running, and focus itself when it receives a request. If the app finds out on launch that another instance is already running, create a HTTP client instead, connect to the HTTP server of the other instance and send a request to it; when the request is completed, exit.

Example implementation (to be put at the beginning of your app.js file):

```
// enclose the logic in a closure, just to play it safe
(function(pidFile) {

    // if creating the PID file fails, i.e. there is another instance
    // of the app already running
    if (!pidFile.touch()) {

        // create a HTTP client
        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({});

        // add some event handlers
        client.onload = function() {
            Ti.App.exit();

        };

        client.onerror = function() {
            Ti.App.exit();

        };

        // and dispatch
        client.open('GET', 'http://localhost:9731/');
        client.send();

    } else {
        // or, if creating the PID file succeeds,
        // create a HTTP server and listen for incoming requests
        var server = Ti.Network.createHTTPServer();

        server.bind(9731, 'localhost', function(request, response) {
            // this handler gets run when another instance of the app
            // is launched; that's where you want to show the app window
            // if it is hidden and focus it

            if (!Ti.UI.getMainWindow().isVisible()) {
                Ti.UI.getMainWindow().show();

            }

            Ti.UI.getMainWindow().focus();

            // send some response back to the other instance
            response.setContentType('text/plain');
            response.setContentLength(2);
            response.setStatusAndReason('200', 'OK');
            response.write('OK');

        });

        // an important thing is to clean up on application exit
        //  - you want to remove the PID file once the application
        // exits, or you wouldn't be able to run it again until you
        // deleted the file manually, something you don't want the end user
        // to deal with
        Ti.API.addEventListener(Ti.EXIT, function() {
            server.close();
            pidFile.deleteFile();

        });

    }

// now call the closure passing in an instance of the Ti.Filesystem.File class
// wrapping the PID file in you app data directory
})(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.API.Application.getDataPath(), 'run.pid'));
```

There may be a more light-weight way to connect the two instances through the `Ti.Network.TCPSocket` class (I'm looking into that myself right now). Another thing to bear in mind is that the app can crash, failing to clean up after itself and thus, subsequently, failing to run at all. So in the `onerror` event handler of the HTTPClient, a more prudent approach than quitting would be to present the user with a dialogue along the lines of "The app is either already running and not responding, or it has recently crashed. Would you like to force start the app?" Also, the port of the server may be already used by another app or, possibly, a zombie from a crashed previous run of your app - the code provided does not take that into account (just sayin').